# Running same job parallely in datastage

Tags: parallel-processing, datastage

How can we run same job with different job parameters PARALLEL in sequencer in  data stage..?
If its possible by instantiating then how...?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide any code that shows what you've tried so far?  We can better guide you to a solution if we know what you've already done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the facility of Allow Multiple instance option. Which creates multiple instance based on the Invocation ID, so multiple instance of same job can run parallaly in datastage server with different parameters. The Allowable multiple instance is available in the Job property.

Answer (score 0):

You create a sequence job and put the job twice and assign each one to a parameter